Is brown-colored serotonin suitable as analytical standard?
We received serotonin, analytical standard, CAS 50-67-9 14927-25MG from Sigma with the expiration date 2027-02-28 and the quality release date 2024-03-12.
However, the substance appears dark-brown in color and is sticky semi-crystalline/tar-alike. Has poor solubility in water and alcohol, but soluble in DMSO at the levels of 10 mg/ml. The certificate of analysis deems the aforementioned color ("very dark-brown") as acceptable. I would think the color arises from decomposition products and the suitable standard ideally should appear as white crystalline powder.
Can this substance still be recognised and used as an analytical standard, in particular for LC-MS/MS? Also, what could cause such change in color that the supplier considered it acceptable?



What does the LC-MS of it look like?

@Waylander We haven't tried to analyse it yet, will test with the initial solution in DMSO once the LC-MS is free.

Looks like it's neutral amine, they aren't terribly stable.

There are a number of oxidation pathways noted in the literature though many are in biological system

The color change might be acceptable.  Usually with the types of impurities caused by oxidation and polymerization of polycyclic aromatic ring systems, the color intensity of the impurities is very large.  Since your CoA says it's ">=95%" pure, that means all the color could be from only 5% of impurity.
